# Sorting words using rawquery

Tags: android, sqlite, sorting

I want to be able to sort words in ascending order using raw query (since I will be using a cursor). However, when I tried to sorting the words alphabetically, my app crashed, giving me this error:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "SELECTWORDFROM": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECTWORDFROM WORDSORDER BYWORD
```

The following shows the code where the error occured.

**WordsDataSource.java**

```
public Cursor sortWords (){
        String[] wordname = new String[]{ WordsHelper.COLUMN_WORD };
        Cursor cursor = mDatabase.rawQuery
            ("SELECT"+ TextUtils.join(", ", wordname)+"FROM " +
                    WordsHelper.TABLE_WORDS +
                    "ORDER BY"+ TextUtils.join(", ", wordname),null);
        //Cursor cursor= mDatabase.query(WordsHelper.TABLE_WORDS,wordname , null, null, null, null, WordsHelper.COLUMN_WORD+" ASC");

return cursor;
    }
```

**WordsHelper.java (my actual database)**

```
package mapp.com.sg.pocketdictionary.db;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class WordsHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String TABLE_WORDS ="WORDS";
    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_ID";
    public static final String COLUMN_WORD = "WORD";
    public static final String COLUMN_MEANING = "MEANING";
    public static final String COLUMN_TYPE = "TYPE";
    public static final String COLUMN_FAVOURITE = "FAVOURITE";

    private static final String DB_NAME = "words.db";
    private static final int DB_VER = 1;
    private static final String DB_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_WORDS+
            " (" + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT" +
            ", " + COLUMN_WORD + " TEXT, "  +
            COLUMN_MEANING + " TEXT,"+
            COLUMN_TYPE + " TEXT,"+ COLUMN_FAVOURITE +" INTEGER)";


    public WordsHelper(Context context){
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VER);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(DB_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

    }
}
```

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Unfortunately, your code does not show precisely whence the error is.  Print out the raw SQL your code generates, and my guess is you will immediately see what the problem is.

Comment: @john tan please look at my current update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `Arrays.ToString()` method which is the cause of the error. 
try converting the array to string using `TextUtils.join(", ", wordname)`

`Arrays.toString()` returns **"debug-style"** string i.e."[WORD]". instead of "[WORD]" you need WORD

**update**

look at the current error

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "SELECTWORDFROM": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECTWORDFROM WORDSORDER BYWORD
```

You need to add **space** after SELECT and after ORDER also

try the following

```
mDatabase.rawQuery
            ("SELECT "+ TextUtils.join(", ", wordname)+" FROM " +
                    WordsHelper.TABLE_WORDS +
                    " ORDER BY "+ TextUtils.join(", ", wordname),null);
```